# Cannot import ng-zorro-antd modules while testing

Tags: angular, ts-jest, ng-zorro-antd

I cannot import modules from ng-zorro-antd in unittests, but I can build the app without any error. I'm using Angular 12.2.4 and ng-zorro-antd 12.1.1

I get the following error:

```
Error: Unexpected value 'NzButtonModule' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation.
```

Here my spec file:

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {NzButtonModule} from 'ng-zorro-antd/button';

import { AntViewComponent } from './ant-view.component';

describe('AntViewComponent', () => {
  let component: AntViewComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AntViewComponent>;

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [NzButtonModule],
        declarations: [AntViewComponent],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
      }).compileComponents();
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AntViewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Did I do something wrong? This is very weird since I can run the app fine, import and use the modules from ng-zorro-antd but I can't in unittests.

Answer (score 0):

Using an older version of ng-zorro-antd resolved the issue (12.0.1).